# What happens when two variables hoisting with the same name?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

So if i declare two variables like this:

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;
```

Javascript compiles code and until the assignment occurred these variables are `undefined`.

But if i write like that:

```
var a = 5;
var a = 10;
```

what happens when these variables hoisting?They both have name `a` and 
they are `undefined`?Or maybe it's one variable and `undefined` is written twice in it?

Comment: There can only be one variable in a scope with a given name, so the second `var` declaration only assigns `10` to the same `a` from the first `var` declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoisting isn't really relevant here. You can't have two variables with the same name in the same scope. As many times as you write `var a`, there is just *one* variable `a`, which is hoisted no differently than if you had a single `var a`.

This code...

```
function() {
  var a = 5;
  var a = 10;
}
```

is functionally equivalent to this code, with `a` hoisted:

```
function () {
  var a;
  a = 5;
  a = 10;
}
```